# What are the basic fonts available in html without adding any external fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

i am creating a text editor which is have to be very very light weighed. 
so i decide to use the already installed fonts in html language.

```
font-family:'Arial';
font-family:'cursive';
font-family:'impact';
```

Comment: Look at [web-friendly fonts](https://websitesetup.org/web-safe-fonts-html-css/).

Answer (score 1):

HTML doesn't "have fonts". HTML is just for page structuring. CSS is used to specify what font you want to use.

Different fonts are recognized by different browsers. So you may want to look into what fonts are recognized across multiple browsers ("web-safe fonts").

You can find one list on w3schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp